# HTML & ASP MVC 4: error CS1056: Unexpected character '\'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, escaping

I am using asp mvc 4. I have the following html markup.

```
<input type="text" maxLength="2000" pattern="^(~/|https?://).*$|^mailto:([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" >
```

I am receiving the following server error: `HttpCompileException - error CS1056: Unexpected character '\'`

I tried to escape it but it didn`t work. This must be simple but I am missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Solution**

The problem was in the `@` symbol. It should be escaped because it is used by the Razor view engine.

This works:

```
pattern="^(~/|https?://).*$|^mailto:([\w\.\-]+)&#64;([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use value of pattern's attribute as string literal:

```
<input type="text" maxLength="2000" pattern='@(@"^(~/|https?://).*$|^mailto:([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$")' >

//better:    
@{
    const string urlPattern = @"^(~/|https?://).*$|^mailto:([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$";
    }
<input type="text" maxLength="2000" pattern="@urlPattern" >
```